# Problem with creating several enemies with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a newbie to python ,so I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong. I have been following a tutorial about pygame, and I reached a section in which multiple enemies are being created. The section goes like this:

```
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 2

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('ufo.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 736))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(0.3)
    enemyY_change.append(40)
```

The enemies are there, but only one is visibly there. It's almost like the other one is behind the background. If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

EDIT: Here is the whole main loop. Some of it is not here so it isn't too long

```
running = True
while running:

screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
# Background Image

screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

# Enemy movement
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
    if enemyX[i] <= 0:
        enemyX_change[i] = 0.3
        enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
    elif enemyX[i] >= 736:
        enemyX_change[i] = -0.3
        enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

    # Collision
    collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
    if collision:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = 'ready'
        score += 100
        print(score)
        enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
        enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)

enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

player(playerX, playerY)
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: The issue is related to the code which draws the enemies, rather than to the code which constructs the lists.

Comment: Please share the whole main loop so we have soemthing to go on.

Comment: Show us the code that draws the enemies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The drawing of the enemies must be done in the loop that iterates through the enemies rather than after the loop:

```py
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    # [...]

    #-->| INDENTATION
    enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)
```